# Python - True part of if condition always executes

Tags: python, if-statement

No matter what's the value of *what*, the true part of if condition is always executed.

```
what = ""
def sendPacket(where, what):
        print("sendPacket()> i/p what :" + what)
        if what:
            zb.send('tx',dest_addr_long = where,dest_addr = UNKNOWN,data = what)
            print('sendPacket()> Data: '+ what) 
            print('sendPacket()> Data sent to: '+ where )
        else:
            print('sendPacket()> data not sent')
```

I want the true part to be executed only when *what* is not equal to null or empty.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling `sendPacket`? Can you print `what`? What's the output?

Comment: Maybe there's some space character.

Comment: Your global `what` has nothing to do with the `what` argument in `sendPacket()`. What matters is what you pass it as an argument when you call it. Try `print(repr(what))` in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask explicitly for the condition you want:

```
if what and not what.isspace():
```

The above states that `what` is not null, is not an empty string, and is not a string of just whitespaces. It's possible that your input has some line break, tab, or other non-printable character that's messing with the test.

Comment: @HussainChachuliya my pleasure! I'm glad it's working now :)

Comment: Why not just `if what.strip()`? Signifies much more concise the intent IMHO.

Comment: @deets that'll fail if `what` is null, also it'll create an additional string object which we discard immediately.

Comment: It seems the OP never had a None, but yup, that's true. I still find `if what and what.strip()` easier to understand because of the lack of negation. YMMV. And the micro-optimization of not creating an object is IMHO not really an issue (O(n) complexity holds for both anyways) - this happens all the time in Python, clarity trumps performance unless for proven cases where it hurts. *MY* head would for sure hurt after coming back to this line after a few month, needing to understand ;)

Comment: @deets a bit of nitpicking: Certainly, both approaches have `O(n)` _time complexity_, but unlike yours, mine uses `O(1)` _space complexity_ ;) . But I agree that yours is easier to read.

Comment: Yes, i thought I said so - at least that's what I meant with "holds for both". But anyway, this is a nitpickfest- the solution and problem comprehension were the hard bits you solved :)